# How to resolve the error 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python, I have imported a file into jupyter as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\shalotte1\Documents\EBQS_INTEGRATEDQUOTEDOCUMENT\groceries.csv")
```

I am using the following code to determine the number of rows and columns in the data

```
df.shape()
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `df.shape` - this will return a tuple as in `(n_rows, n_cols)`. You are then trying to call this tuple as though it were a function.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to python, I would recommend you to read this page. This will make you get aware of other causes too so that you can solve this problem again if it appears in the future.

https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-tuple-object-is-not-callable/